# components load before call angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-components

I am working on angular js components there are two components that will called when their respective button is clicked

**Issue**: when the page loads both components are initialized , but in real they should be initialized when I click on the respective component
example:

**index.html**

```
    <div class='breadcrumbs'>
   <div class='inner'>
      <ul class='cf' style="    margin-top: 0px;">
         <li ng-click="WizardsViewerCtrl.createFirst()">

         </li>
         <li ng-click="WizardsViewerCtrl.createSecond()">
         <span>Arrange Questions</span> </a>

         </li>

      </ul>
   </div>
</div>

      <div ng-show="viewFirstRoute">
         <first-component></first-component>
      </div>
      <div ng-show="viewSecondRoute">
         <second-component></second-component>

      </div>
```

**index.js**

```
$scope.viewFirstRoute=false;
$scope.viewSecondRoute=false;



function createFirst() {

    $scope.viewFirstRoute=true;
    $scope.viewSecondRoute=false;


}

function createSecond() {
   $scope.viewFirstRoute=false;
    $scope.viewSecondRoute=true;


}
```

problem is when this page **index.html** is loaded ,both components are initialized

**first.component.js**

```
angular
.module('AOTC')
.component('firstComponent', {
        templateUrl: 'first.html',
        controllerAs: 'firstCtrl',
        controller:(function ($scope) {
            console.log("first component loaded");//it prints while index.html is loaded even i didn't clicked on this component
           })});
```

**second.component.js**

```
angular
.module('AOTC')
.component('secondComponent', {
        templateUrl: 'second.html',
        controllerAs: 'secondCtrl',
        controller:(function ($scope) {
            console.log("second component loaded");//it prints while index.html is loaded even i didn't clicked on second component
           })});
```

**summarizing**: two components on same route must be initialized when I click on the respective component , but behavior noticed components are loaded as soon as **route is loaded** it doesn't care about the click, see **comments** in the JS file

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-if instead of ng-show. it should fix the issue.

```
<div ng-if="viewFirstRoute">
         <first-component></first-component>
 </div>
 <div ng-if="viewSecondRoute">
     <second-component></second-component>
  </div>
```

> ng-show: it will add component to DOM but set its display property to none.
>   ng-if: Will add or remove component from DOM conditionally.